# Which expressions, verbs, vocabulary... Should I use in the writing for the B2?

Tags: vocabulary, expressions, phrasal-verbs, compounds

I'm going to take an exam of the B2, and I wanted to know, what is the vocabulary, the expressions... Etc... That they want? 
Because all I can find in every website is "complex expressions... Vocabulary", but that's just not explanatory

Comment: I am voting to close this question since it's off topic.

Comment: @Cardinal Oh, I thought this was the right community of stack to post this question. Do you know where can I post it instead?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, maybe google is a good place to start!